# Which one is better and cheaper for rails apps? Heroku or Google App Engine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-app-engine, heroku

I am beginner in ROR. I am working on one project. I want to know the better option between for deployment of the app.

Comment: Heroku is ideal because it's relatively easy to get up and running, also it's free if you're just learning and won't have a lot of traffic on your app.  (I don't know about Google App Engine).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer will be more conceptual, rather then technical.

This is the first time I hear about Google App Engine in case of Rails. This is mostly a crucial reason, why I would say, that you definitely better go with **Heroku**.

While you are a beginner, it's better to use the most widely spread solutions and tools. **Heroku** has a huge history and you can find any answers in the internet very easily. It's well known among rails community and everyone can make a small consultation according to it.

Even if Google App Engine would be better or cheaper (haven't checked it), you shouldn't start such experiments until you have good deploy/rails knowledge.